# What's the cheapest way to send luggage abroad?

Tags: budget, europe, luggage, shipping

I am planning to travel from Portugal to Estonia hitchhiking, but I need to get rid of my luggage before, which is a regular-sized suitcase. Does anyone have recommendations how I could send my luggage to Estonia by the cheapest option possible?

The arrival of the luggage is not very urgent.

Comment: The cheapest way, as always, is to carry it, and walk to your destination. But that's probably not what you're looking for... and is one reason that price-shopping questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Also, shipping luggage isn't usually considered part of travel, and is thus probably off-topic despite being a price-shopping question. Even so,there are some similar questions on this site--have you searched to see if any of them provide a reasonable answer for you?

Comment: @Flimzy I would disagree on shipping point.  While it is unusual its not unheard of.

Comment: I think sending luggage ahead of travel is on-topic on a travel site.  Price shopping may not be.  Sending luggage ahead may or may not be cheaper than carrying it, depending on the luggage in question.

Comment: @Flimzy Shipping luggage ahead has become a regular part of my inner-European travels as it is often cheaper than taking it as extra luggage on low fare airlines.

Comment: @Karlson: We may need a meta question on this topic, then, as many questions like this have been closed as being about shipping rather than about travel.

Comment: I think is a valid question for specific routes such as the Camino, but this seems a bit too general given the complexities of moving goods across international borders.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Chronopost](http://www.chronopost.pt/#3)? In my experience it is among the cheapest international carriers operating in Portugal.

Portugal -> Estonia is about 42€ for 30 kg (60 x 40 x 40 cm).

Call them and they will even pick up your package / suitcase. Make sure that you close it properly (zipper is not enough, you will need tape or a lock to fit their guidelines).

Comment: @Stockfishch can you elaborate  a bit more on your comment above "Shipping luggage ahead has become a regular part of my inner-European travels". I am very interested on this topic. How do you do it, and which companies do you use?